# Max execution time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site which is hosted on a dev site for demonstration to the client, and everything works without problem. However, when I download the files and database to my local EasyPHP installation, I receive the following error:

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of
>   30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\EasyPHP-5.3.4.0\www\PC
>   Estimating\classes\database.class.php
>   on line 23

The database details for the connection are correct, as the Database object is already used on part of the template before this error is shown.

My question is, why does the system work fine on a live server, but not on EasyPHP?

Comment: My crystal ball tells me that you forgot the indexes on one of your tables in your local MySQL

Comment: Small note - max_execution_time is not applied to queris, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check the max_execution_time setting in the php.ini files on your server and on your local installation.

btw... what is done in line 23 ?

Copied from my comment to make it easier to find the solution:

*some things really runs slower on windows... while on mac/unix the php connects to mysql using a file socket while it should use tcpip in windows. Try using "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" when connecting to the db*

Comment: some things really runs slower on windows... while on mac/unix the php connects to mysql using a file socket while it should use tcpip in windows. Try using "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" when connecting to the db

Comment: Changing the hostname to 127.0.0.1 from localhost did the trick. Thanks @Bastian!

Comment: @Bastian: thank you kind sir! what's the cause of localhost vs 127?

Comment: Wow. This is one the most useful and Miraculous answers I've ever found stack overflow. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These issue have two possible solutions:

1) Increase the max_execution_time in your php.ini . First of all, locate this file, and then edit it. Locate this line:

`max_execution_time=30`

and replace by:

`max_execution_time=120`

And then restart your webserver.

This will increase from 30 seconds to 120 seconds. You can increase even more, according to your application needs.

2) If this setting doesn't solve the problem, you may have to look into your PHP application, because there may be an infinite loop or something similar.

More details about this problem: 
https://www.copahost.com/blog/increase-php-max-execution-time/

Answer (score -1):

Because your PC is slow compared to server and/or your code is really badly optimised

Comment: Hardly. When I run the exact same code on MAMP installed on a MacBook, everything works fine...

Comment: Ok - this was first shot - what version of EasyPHP ? ( and just for sure i'm wrong - what processor / ram on machine with EasyPHP )

Comment: The code was working fine up until this evening. EasyPHP version 5.3.4.0 with 6 GB of RAM and AMD Athlon X4 630 2.80 GHz...

Comment: And what changed this evening ? or you tried it for first time this evening on this machine ?